# What IDE to use to start contributing code for CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

It's my first question here on stackoverflow so please be easy on me. 
I've been trying to set up the source for CKEditor so I can start contributing to this editor. I have followed this link: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_contributing_code but I got stuck on step 4 as I haven't got the following file: bender.js. I also need something called gruntfile for step 5. Do you know where I can get them from as when I fork https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev, the following project does not come with them. Also, what IDE do I need to use to develop code? Sorry, for this question as it might seem a bit stupid but I come from the Java background and Node.js is really new to me, therefore I'm struggling a bit here.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You don't need to use any IDE. A text editor will do. The documentation also explains how to get the required dependencies with npm

Comment: Can you point me at the right direction for that documentation? The files I wrote about are missing from the package I downloaded from github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev. The package.json file was also missing but I managed to grab it from the internet

Answer (score 2):

There are no requirements regarding IDE, at the end it's all just text.

Regarding your problems: **Make sure you're forking [ckeditor-dev](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev)**, and not [ckeditor-releases](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases) repository. Only dev repository contains all the helpers like gruntfile.

The gruntfile [is there](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/8a5e2265aa5902ad6509f7f6252b82e19ef0da21/gruntfile.js) so if you cloned CKEditor repository, you must have it.

Then all you need to do is follow up the instructions of [CKEditor contribution guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_contributing_code) closesly, and you're good to go!